# artifactory vagrant repo, getting json or 404 response when trying to download the image

Tags: vagrant, artifactory, download

Good time of the day all, I have setup a pro version of artifactory and I have setup a vagrant repo with 1 file. however, when i try to get the file from artifactory i get the following response instead of downloading the file and this is due to setting incorrect repo layout. by default artifactory sets a simple-default layout that I think is causing the issue

```
{"name":"vagrant-centos-base.box","description":null,"short_description":null,"versions":[]}
```

Obviously, when i try to use vagrant up command with the url to the repo/file specified i get the following error:

```
bsdtar.EXE: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
```

which i strongly suspect is due to the vagrant downloading that response instead of the actual file.

What am I missing?

Thank You in advance!

here is the output from vagrant:

```
Bringing machine 'webserver' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'webserver1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'appserver' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> webserver: Box 'vagrant-centos-base' could not be found. Attempting to find
and install...
    webserver: Box Provider: virtualbox
    webserver: Box Version: >= 0
==> webserver: Loading metadata for box 'https://{url}/artifa
ctory/api/vagrant/B6_Vagrant/vagrant-centos-base'
    webserver: URL: https://{url}/artifactory/api/vagrant/B6_
Vagrant/vagrant-centos-base
==> webserver: Adding box 'vagrant-centos-base' (v1.0.0) for provider: virtualbo
x
    webserver: Downloading: https://{url}/B6_Vagrant/vagrant-
centos-base.box
    webserver: Progress: 0% (Rate: 0curl:/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
    webserver:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

as you can see, now its getting the medatada, but its failing to download the file since the artifactory is giving 404. same as when i try to do it manually

Comment: to add to that, when i click on the download link on the page for the artifact in the artifactory, it redirects to another link that is missing a part of the URI and gives me a 404. I am completely new to the artifact repositories and I was hoping vagrant repo would be a simple way to start

Comment: What is the URL you are downloading the file from?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the URI piece is artifactory/api/vagrant/B6_Vagrant/vagrant-centos-base.box and its giving me the 404. Could this be due to the incorrect layout? I am not sure how to check where the actual file is located

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you uploaded the vagrant box to Artifactory without provide the box metadata - name, provider, version.
When vagrant is trying to download the box via the vagrant API, it expects a JSON response which describes the image and provided a download link, for example:

```
{"name":"debian-current","description":null,"short_description":null,"versions":[{"version":"12","status":"active","description_html":null,"description_markdown":null,"providers":[{"name":"Provider","url":"http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local-vagrant/debian-current.box"}]}]}
```

If this metadata is missing, vagrant does not know how to proceed.

You can still install a box uploaded without metadata. You will have to use a direct download URL for the box (not passing via the Vagrant API), for example:

```
vagrant box add http://myserver/B6_Vagrant/vagrant-centos-base.box --name vagrant-centos-base.box
```

This will return the actual bits of the box. Notice that you will have to provide the `vagrant add` command with the name of the images using the `--name` parameter.

Uploading the box with the metadata can be done using the deployment UI or the REST API.
You can use the "Set Me Up" feature for getting detailed instructions which will help with the process
[image]

For more info please take a look at the [Vagrant Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Vagrant+Repositories) section in the Artifactory documentation

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I did manage to configure the metadata, now i get the following response '{"name":"vagrant-centos-base","description":null,"short_description":null,"versions":[{"version":"1.0.0","status":"active","description_html":null,"description_markdown":null,"providers":[{"name":"virtualbox","url":"https://webserver/B6_Vagrant/vagrant-centos-base.box"}]}]}'.

Comment: So when i issue vagrant up command it gets the metadata, but when it tries to download the image from "https://webserver/B6_Vagrant/vagrant-centos-base.box i get the 404. I get the same 404 when i click on download button in the gui. So I am not sure what is causing that at the moment

Comment: forgot to add, i followed the instructions on the artifactory page regardin vagrant repo setup to the bone, but still keep getting the issue

Comment: How do you handle names with "/" in the uri?  For example, if you have a box with the name `ubuntu/trusty64`, it 404's if you try and `vagrant box add http://myserver/vagrant-local/ubuntu/trusty64.box`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out i had to add the /artifactory to the artifactory URL in the settings. This way url in the metadata started to point to the correct location and and its all working now